# Indexing PDF content in zip folder is not working - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, pdf, sharepoint-search

I have a requirement to search within pdf file content that is stored in a zip file. We are using SharePoint 2013 Search Services with OOB functionality (no iFilters installed).

The zip file in sucesffully crawled, searching for the name of the pdf file in the zip folder is working but not the content. Although if  the pdf is uploaded to the library outside the zip folder, search results are correct.

It seems as if it is not indexing the pdf document if it is listed in zip folder. Other file types (Ex: docx or txt) are indexed and results are returned for content searching.

There is an [article for SharePoint 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2568871/fast-search-not-indexing-pdf-content-inside-a-zip-file) indicating that an iFilter shall be installed but it should be oudated and this issue should be already solved.

Appreciate if you have information if there is anything missing or additional configuration shall be done.

Thanks

Comment: When you open the pdf is it searchable or is it a scan of the document? If it is a scan you would have to employ custom indexing coupled with OCR.

Comment: the pdf is text-searchable. The same pdf file is uploaded outside the zip folder and the content was searchable

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the file names of zip file contents are indexed but the contents is not. You may need to investigate a third party iFilter for that feature or change your workflow so that you don't use zipped PDFs.

Comment: With office documents, like word, the file contents are indexed even in zip file. The pdf file is itself indexed if outside zip folder. It is just the combination of pdf in zip.